# Handling MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE from video decoder MFT

Tags: c++, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to decode even just a single H264 frame with the `H264 Decoder MFT`, but I've been having problems with `ProcessOutput()`. I've reduced the bad `HRESULT`'s as much as I can, but I'm currently stuck on dealing with `MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE`. This occurs after I set the pSample equal to my allocated `output_sample` and call `ProcessOutput()`, since this decoder requires you allocate your own sample. I tried resetting the output type using `SetOutputType()` to what I had in my `configure_decoder()` function, but alas I get a bad HRESULT. Not sure what to do next.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to follow [this at Handling Stream Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/handling-stream-changes#output-type):

> 2. The client calls `IMFTransform::GetOutputAvailableType`. This method returns an updated set of output types.
> 3. The client calls `SetOutputType` to set a new output type.
> 4. The client resumes calling `ProcessInput`/`ProcessOutput`.

In the question body above you are trying to do 3 without doing 2. Most likely your media type is somewhat different from MFT's so it is likely to reject it and it blocks the processing until this is resolved.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick with the error. I updated the original question so other users can see what I did.

Now, when viewing the outputted NV12, I notice the colors are messed up. They almost appear to be shifted down - any idea why this occurs?  https://i.imgur.com/zzdCZIV.png I am also using these settings in the viewer to view the NV12 file, if it matters at all https://i.imgur.com/Q5Uf95d.png

Comment: I'd say you'd just continue the loop and do retry with `ProcessOutput` rather than creating a separate call but it's okay. I am pretty sure you get valid output overall but they way you do it it's not clear what is wrong. First, you need to make sure you change type to NV12 and not a different format. You have no checks for this. Second, what is the data you are getting exactly? Or at least what exactly the viewer shows you, there is too much guessing involved.

Comment: I edited the original post so it continues the loop as you suggested and sets the output type to NV12. https://imgur.com/a/WErqANl < here are 3 images which should show the data.

Comment: 1 - the code is incorrect now, you are not supposed to set NV12 in changed format handler, you are supposed to choose NV12 from available media types in the case there are a few offered for your choice; 2 - I still don't understand what is wrong with the frame itself

Comment: Well I have no idea either. According to your program, the index for NV12 is zero anyways so i doubt its related to the GetAvailableOutputs(). I will keep trying to fix it as best as I can, but i may end up opening another question on here if im unable to

Comment: What you essentially need is to extract this into smallest possible console app and upload it on github with a sample H.264 input vector. This will add some context and I am guessing the problem in the code would become obvious.

Comment: I have added you to it